# GWT Calendrical Calculations

Tags: javascript, algorithm, gwt, calendar

We have a GWT application that needs to display various holidays. Is there a library available to do these calendrical calculations? If not, we'll have to do our own that we can ingest a set of rules to.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the GWT port of [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) called [Goda](http://github.com/mping/gwt-joda-time). Maybe this will help you?

-JP

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach might be to grap some calendars off the web, such as those at

[this site](http://www.calendarlabs.com/ical-calendar-holidays.php).

I have no connection with the site, and am not making any recommendation about the quality or comprehensivity of their calendars.

Oh, and you have Googled for **calendrical calculations** haven't you ?  To find the source ...

Comment: Google? What is this Google you speak of :-P I did a brief search for GWT specific (since GWT can't use Java's Calendar class and only uses Date) but didn't come up with anything. I should look for the calcs directly though.

Comment: I took a look at that site and doesn't really provide what we need.

Answer (score 0):

[`com.google.gwt.user.datepicker.client.CalendarUtil`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/datepicker/client/CalendarUtil.html) has a few methods that could be useful.

JP already mentioned Goda time. I haven't used Goda, but Joda time is generally a great API. Additionally, there are a few other libraries:

http://github.com/mping/gwt-joda-time

http://code.google.com/p/gwt-time/

Comment: BTW, I'd really like to find out myself, which of the libraries has the most promising future: http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/941a5c09f366d9de#